# Simple DFS stuck in an infinite loop c++

Tags: c++, depth-first-search

I am trying to implement a simple DFS in C++ with `n` number of nodes and `k` number of edges.

For some reason it is getting stuck in an infinite loop:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

#define pb push_back
#define MAXV 1000

void addEdge(vector<int> adj[], int u, int v){
    adj[u].pb(v);
    adj[v].pb(u);
}

void DFSUtil(int u, vector<int> adj[], vector<int>& visited){
    visited[u] = 1;
    cout << u << " ";
    for(int i = 0;i<adj[u].size();i++){
        if(visited[adj[u][i]] == 0){
            DFSUtil(u,adj,visited);
        }
    }
}

void DFS(vector<int> adj[], int N){
    vector<int> visited(N, 0);
    for(int u = 1;u<N;u++){
        if(visited[u] == 0){
            DFSUtil(u,adj,visited);
            cout << "\n";
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    int n,k,m,i,u,v;
    scanf("%d %d",&n,&k);

    vector<int> adj[n+1];

    for(i = 0;i<k;i++){
        scanf("%d %d",&u,&v);
        addEdge(adj,u,v);
    }

    // find connected components
    DFS(adj,n+1);


    return 0;
}
```

Could someone point me where am I going wrong with this code?

Sample input to test on:

```
4 3
1 2
2 3
1 4
```

Comment: Did you try stepping through your code with a debugger, to figure out _why_ your code is getting stuck in an infinite loop?

Comment: I tried putting printf statements and getchar() to understand what's going on. I found that it is getting stuck in the DFSUtil function. But still don't know the reason why.

Comment: I certainly feel there is something wrong in the way I modified the passed vector in a recursion.

Comment: Dig deeper, try printing more stuff

Comment: Yes, just need a confirmation. Is that the proper way to modify the vector `visited` which is passed by reference in the recursion ?

Comment: @user3243499 And, that's why I suggested using a debugger. You can look at values of all the variables, at each step of the algorithm, without needing to plow through the output, when, eventually, it starts looping.

Comment: Got it. Best thing in stackoverflow is that sometimes I am forced to bang my head on the wall and find the answer myself

Answer (score 1):

After navigating through every steps, finally, I am able to find the bug.

The passed value should have been `DFSUtil(adj[u][i],adj,visited);` instead of `DFSUtil(u,adj,visited);` which actually calls the same vertex again and again and hence the infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
void DFSUtil(int u, vector<int> adj[], vector<int>& visited){
    visited[u] = 1;
    cout << u << " ";
    for(int i = 0;i<adj[u].size();i++){
        int to = adj[u][i];
        if(visited[to] == 0){
            DFSUtil(to, adj, visited);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What did not you understand?

Comment: Not for me, for everyone. :) Posting just a code block without pointing out what did you do/add/modify and why, is not useful and may lead to downvotes.

Comment: My code is copied from askers code. I have corrected DFSUtil function, where I saw mistake.